# Outside mouse click of the popup control WPF

Tags: wpf, popup

We have requirement to show popup. On click outside of the control it automatically closed .For example click any button that button action triggers . The requirement popup should work like combo box . When click out of bound it closes the dropdown and any other would not trigger. I do that using mouse capture and works for the button click . But on click the tab control selection is happens .How to stop the mouse interception.

Thanks
Sekar

Answer (score 0):

To make the popup close when you click outside it, you can set your popup's `StaysOpen` property to `false`.

As for stopping the mouse click from triggering on other controls, perhaps you can use this trick:
When your popup is opened, temporarily set the `IsHitTestVisible` property of your window to `false`. And when it is closed, set it back to `true`, for example:

```
<Popup x:Name="popup1" StaysOpen="False" Opened="popup1_Opened" Closed="popup1_Closed">
```

And the code behind:

```
private void popup1_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    window1.IsHitTestVisible = false;
}

private void popup1_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    window1.IsHitTestVisible = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer . My question is how to stop the mouse interception with other controls . When click other controls popup should close and none other action should not takes place

Comment: Oops.. Sorry I overlooked the last part of your question and misunderstood it. I have updated my answer, please check if it could answer your question.